# Checkout on gerrit patchset with LINK

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gerrit

let's assume that everything I know is gerrit link. Is it possible to checkout on such commit? 
so I've got
    https://gerrit.com/#/c/4840847/
The patchset is not specified so I want to checkout on the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the legacy number `4840847`, you can get the ref of the current patchset with Gerrit's ssh command `gerrit query`.

```
ssh -p 29418 <username>@<host> gerrit query change:4840847 --current-patch-set | awk '/^    ref:/{print $NF}'
```

If successful, it returns the ref of the latest patchset, `refs/changes/47/4840847/5` for example. `--format=json` can be used to return data in json. `gerrit query` returns more than the ref. The project name is available too, with which you can compose the commands to fetch and checkout the revision.

```
git fetch ssh://<username>@<host>:29418/<projectname> refs/changes/47/4840847/5 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```